# Python ctypes - Setting c_char array when string has embedded null?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm using ctypes bit fields to dissect tightly packed binary data.  I stuff a record's worth of data into a union as a string, then pull out key fields as integers.

This works great when there are no nulls in the buffer, but any embedded nulls cause cytpes to truncate the string.

Example:

```
from ctypes import *

class H(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [ ('f1', c_int, 8),
                 ('f2', c_int, 8),
                 ('f3', c_int, 8),
                 ('f4', c_int, 2)
                 # ...
                 ]

class U(Union):
    _fields_ = [ ('fld', H),
                 ('buf', c_char * 6)
                 ]

# With no nulls, works as expected...
u1 = U()
u1.buf='abcabc'
print '{} {} {} (expect: 97 98 99)'.format(u1.fld.f1, u1.fld.f2, u1.fld.f3)

# Embedded null breaks it...  This prints '97 0 0', NOT '97 0 99'
u2 = U()
u2.buf='a\x00cabc'
print '{} {} {} (expect: 97 0 99)'.format(u2.fld.f1, u2.fld.f2, u2.fld.f3)
```

Browsing the ctypes source, I see two methods to set a char array, CharArray_set_value() and  CharArray_set_raw().   It appears that CharArray_set_raw() will handle nulls properly whereas CharArray_set_value() will not.

But I can't figure out how to invoke the raw version...  It looks like a property, so I'd expect something like:

```
ui.buf.raw = 'abcabc'
```

but that yields:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute raw
```

Any guidance appreciated.  (Including a completely different approach!)

(Note: I need to process thousands of records per second, so efficiency is critical.  Using an array comprehension to stuff a byte array in the structure works, but it's 100x slower.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the raw-string array outside of your struct/union:

```
mystring = (c_char * 6).from_buffer(u2)
print mystring.raw
```

This way you don't have any overhead for conversion.
I wonder why a (c_char * 6) behaves differently when used alone vs. used in a Structure/Union...

Comment: For convenience (usually), the `CField` descriptors for `c_char` and `c_wchar` arrays are special-cased in `PyCField_FromDesc` (in Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c) to convert to and from native Python strings using `s_get` / `s_set` and `U_get` / `U_set`.

Comment: Don't use `from_address` for this since the resulting array doesn't own a reference on the source buffer, `u2`. This is a recipe for segfault disaster.  Use `(c_char * 6).from_buffer(u2)`.

Comment: In cases such as this I prefer to make the field name private (e.g. `_buf`) and use a public property.

Answer (score 0):

`c_char*6` is handled, unfortunately, as a nul-terminated string.  Switch to `c_byte*6` instead, but lose the convenience of initializing with strings:

```
from ctypes import *

class H(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [ ('f1', c_int, 8),
                 ('f2', c_int, 8),
                 ('f3', c_int, 8),
                 ('f4', c_int, 2)
                 # ...
                 ]

class U(Union):
    _fields_ = [ ('fld', H),
                 ('buf', c_byte * 6)
                 ]

u1 = U()
u1.buf=(c_byte*6)(97,98,99,97,98,99)
print '{} {} {} (expect: 97 98 99)'.format(u1.fld.f1, u1.fld.f2, u1.fld.f3)

u2 = U()
u2.buf=(c_byte*6)(97,0,99,97,98,99)
print '{} {} {} (expect: 97 0 99)'.format(u2.fld.f1, u2.fld.f2, u2.fld.f3)
```

Output:

```
97 98 99 (expect: 97 98 99)
97 0 99 (expect: 97 0 99)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark.   This works, but the CPU overhead associated with marshaling the bytes from the string into the byte array makes the approach too slow for my application.  (My trials were about 100x slower than ctype's memcpy()).